# .NET CreateRole

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I do:

```
Roles.CreateRole("Role1");
```

I have a role created "`Role1`" which I can then assign to users.

I could not find where is this `Role1` stored at? Meaning if I run my program again it says "`Role1`" already exist. I did a search for "`Role1`" but was not able to find where it was stored at.

Comment: Which Membership Provider do you use? And what is the actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your sql database if you store the membership in sql server. There should be table aspnet_Roles.
All your roles will be there.
You can also access the roles from the asp.net configuration tool under security.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Roles.RoleExists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.roleexists.aspx) if this role defined in your datasource already.

> Gets a value indicating whether the specified role name already exists
>   in the role data source.

```
if (Roles.RoleExists(Role1))
    {

    }
```

Also check with [`Roles.GetAllRoles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.getallroles.aspx) to get all roles in the application.

```
rolesArray = Roles.GetAllRoles();
foreach(var role in rolesArray)
{
   if (role == Role1)
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```